# how to find document in mongodb with its id passed in textbox?

Tags: meteor

I am learning mongodb with meteor js so dont have much knowledge of both mongodb and meteor.

Below is the js code:

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Dbs } from '../lib/collections.js';
import './main.html';

Template.body.helpers({
  /*temp1:[
  {text:'my data1'}'
  {text:'my data1'}
  ]*/

  dbs(){
    return Dbs.find({'user_id':'p123'});
  }
});
```

Basically i just want to pass user id in a textbox and based on it,i want to display the other details of user.In above code i am passing it manually and its working.anyone suggest me what should i do here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the template instance a ReactiveVar that you will update with an event.
Then use it inside the helper, so the helper will re-execute everytime the value change:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  this.currentTextBox = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  "keyup .js-my-textbox"(event, instance) {
    // This event is executed when you type in an input with the class "js-my-textbox"
    instance.currentTextBox.set(event.target.value);
  },
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  dbs() {
    const instance = Template.instance();

    return Dbs.find({'user_id': instance.currentTextBox.get() });
  },
});
```

EDIT:
Example of what could be the html part:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="js-my-textbox">
  {{#each db in dbs}}
    <-- Do what you want, example: -->
    <p>{{db.myField}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: instance.currentTextBox.set(event.target.value); i am not understanding what the above line of code doing ?@Gaëtan Rouziès

Comment: When you are inside helpers/events and onCreated,onRendered function, you can access the template object, (we call it Template instance). Its an object shared in the template, in the code above, you can access it with `this` inside `onCreated` and `Template.instance()` inside helpers and event. We use it to share variable between helper and event. We add the variable `currentTextBox` to the Template instance. And this `instance.currentTextBox.set(event.target.value)` means we set the variable with the value of the textbox.

Comment: okay. Thanks for your help but it is not working for me.I am not understanding what is wrong because i have used the code in way as u said.If possible can you help me in  more detailed way.It will be very useful.

Comment: N what will be the html part ?

Comment: You should go through the official meteor guide if you didn't yet. And/or search: How works: events, helpers, templates in meteor. PS: Edited my answer with an example of html part.

Answer (score 0):

First You Create **Event** Function `Template.body.events({})` to access text .Then store variable to use [Meteor Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html). Then Variable easily access helpers.If session changes variable will be changed.